# How to disconnect telegram client?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

Im trying to write a script in python that listen "first reply" of a bot and then exits. So, I create a client instance and then send a msg to Bot and now I want to record only first reply of bot (upcoming replies can ignored), and save bot reply to Reply variable. Now how to exit from listener mode so that I can do other stuffs after getting reply. I tried **client.disconnect()** and **client.disconnected()** but now working or maybe I don't know proper use of these method. I'm new to telethon APIs.

> When I run this script, a msg from my telegram is sent to
> bot(**BotFather**) and then bot send a reply

Reply from bot father

> I can help you create and manage Telegram bots. If you're new to the
> Bot API, please see the manual (https://core.telegram.org/bots).
>
> You can control me by sending these commands:
>
> /newbot - create a new bot /mybots - edit your bots [beta]
>
> Edit Bots /setname - change a bot's name /setdescription - change bot
> description /setabouttext - change bot about info /setuserpic - change
> bot profile photo /setcommands - change the list of commands
> /deletebot - delete a bot
>
> Bot Settings /token - generate authorization token /revoke - revoke
> bot access token /setinline - toggle inline mode
> (https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) /setinlinegeo - toggle inline
> location requests
> (https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#location-based-results)
> /setinlinefeedback - change inline feedback
> (https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#collecting-feedback) settings
> /setjoingroups - can your bot be added to groups? /setprivacy - toggle
> privacy mode (https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) in groups
>
> Games /mygames - edit your games
> (https://core.telegram.org/bots/games) [beta] /newgame - create a new
> game (https://core.telegram.org/bots/games) /listgames - get a list of
> your games /editgame - edit a game /deletegame - delete an existing
> game

and this reply got assigned in Reply variable

> but my scripts
> still listening for other upcoming events. is there any method from
> which I can close this connection.

```
import random
import traceback
import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest,GetHistoryRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser, PeerChannel

api_id =  #Api_ID
api_hash = #Api_Hash
phone = #session
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
Reply = ' '

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='https://t.me/BotFather'))
async def NewMessageListener(event):
    Reply = event.message.message

with client:
    client.send_message("https://t.me/BotFather", "/start")
    client.run_until_disconnected()

    # Disconnect client to stop run_until_disconnected()

# Do other stuff!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you trying to achieve here but you can disconnect the client using [`disconnect`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.telegrambaseclient.TelegramBaseClient.disconnect) method

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id =  #Api_ID
api_hash = #Api_Hash
phone = #session
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
Reply = ' '

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats='https://t.me/BotFather'))
async def newMessageListener(event):
    reply = event.message.message
    # do stuff with reply then close the client
    await client.disconnect()

async def main():
    async with client:
        await client.send_message("https://t.me/BotFather", "/start")
    await client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: thanks man, its working now. I don't know much more about await keyword and just forget to add this before client.disconnect() thats why my code not working. thanks again ;)